# How to find the angle between a line and a polyline?

Tags: matlab, polyline

How to find the angle between a line (formed by two points) and a polyline with MATLAB?

polyline sample data:

```
X = [59.5001826000000,59.5005297000000,59.5006135000000,59.5012631000000,NaN];
Y = [36.3160562000000,36.3158460000000,36.3157953000000,36.3153916000000,NaN];
```

two points sample data:

```
p1 = [36.3083315600000, 59.5669254100000];
p2 = [36.3083643100000, 59.5667925800000];
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "the angle between them"? There could be lots of angles between a line and a polyline

Comment: You need to do some of your own research and figure out what you can.

Comment: @qxz i mean the angle cause beacause of intersection between this line and polyline

Comment: @OmidGharib A line and a polyline could intersect at multiple points

Comment: @MadPhysicist i know how to do it between two line but a line and a poly its a little bit confusing for me

Comment: @OmidGharib Maybe you want to check the line with each segment of the polyline?

Comment: @qxz yeah thats true what is your suggestion ia it okey to choose randomly two points of the polyline?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah i think its a better solution thank you in advance

Comment: @OmidGharib What is your context for this? Why do you want to do this? What program is it a part of?

Comment: @qxz find angel between a line and this polyline, Polylines are streets and lines are user's gps locations

Comment: @OmidGharib But why do you want the angle between them? What program is this a part of, what is it ultimately supposed to do?

Comment: @qxz to find which line was the path that user drive on it between all pathes